# Functional differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve a functional differential equation of this kind

$$ \int d t'' dt''' a(t,t'') b(t'',t''') \frac{\delta u(t'',t';[x])}{\delta x(t''')}+\int d t'' c(t,t'') x(t'') u(t'',t';[x])+u(t,t';[\varphi])=d(t,t')$$

where $u(t'',t';[x])$ is a functional of $x(t)$ and $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ are known functions. Does it exist a method to solve such an equeation? Coul you suggest any reference?